# JQuery ajax call web method cannot set datatype: json

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I has write a webmethod using c#, the web method as below

```
  [WebMethod]
    public string getname(string name)
    {
        return "my name is" + name.ToString();
    }
```

I create another aspx page to call the web method.  If i set the dataType and contentType, it keep return me an error and alert fail.  If I remove the contentType and datatype, it alert me OK.  But when I alert(data) which is return data from web method, it show me all the html code of the page I created.  I check the browser console, it show me POST http://webservice.aspx/getname 500 (Internal Server Error). What the error I make.  Please help.

```
 function getname()
    {            
        var name = "Peter";
        $.ajax({
            url: '/webservice.aspx/getname',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: "{'name':" + name + "}",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("OK");
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If you are using web method in aspx page it must be static.Modify it -----public static string getname---

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getname()
    {            
        var name = "Peter";
        $.ajax({
            url: '/webservice.aspx/getname',
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {name:name}
            success: function (data) {
                alert("OK");
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Malkam, it seem like the web method do not return data.  the alert data give me a bunch of html source code.

Comment: Check html source code,is it returning any error message?

Comment: the return data is html source code.  Why this will happen?     It not return the data from the web method.  No error from browser console also.  Do you has any idea?

Comment: see what's there in html?

Comment: Malkam, the html return is the source code of the page itself.  and some extra info as below                                           <!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"47e64d7ae932477786921b0457a21902"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:52834/a3ed8fb28dd04614b5ea6d1f95150686/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

Comment: I think the web method need set as static and the data passing format is wrong. Set it like this  data: '{name: "' + name+ '" }',. Then the problem fix.

Answer (score 0):

dataType is define what type the data come in ( to javascript). Not the type the data you sent.

in js:
data: {
  name: name
},

in WebMethod:
return Json.Encode(xxx);